# Where's the search box?

Tags: support

I'm here on the mobile site via my phone, but can't find any manner of search box anywhere. I must be looking in Alderaan places.

Is the search box stripped from the mobile site? Any ideas (besides the last resort of using the desktop site on mobile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the upper right hand corner there is a small square box with a triangle pointing down.  Click the triangle and the search box and login link will appear below it.

[image]

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. I had previously clicked that box, but nothing happened, my browser simply zoomed in. Another click, though, and it opened up. Grazi!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got yourself enough screen real-estate, you can also just switch to the full site.
Scroll down to the bottom...

[image: Screenshot]